# (in jira) Is it possible to search for resolved issues within an open task (while task is used as a log)

Tags: sql, jira, issue-tracking

We have an open task that we use as a log,
within this log we enter the tasks+bugs that are required for the project.
everyone is able to edit this "open task log" and there are many people working on the tasks+bugs.
the question is:
is it possible to create a filter that will show only the resolved tasks+bugs that are on this "open task log" ????
Great day!

Comment: Are these tasks added as subtasks or are these linked?

Comment: Hey, tnx for the inquiry, these tasks are linked as a list (we update this "open task log" as a diary, we link all of the "tasks+bugs" that were resolved and merged.) for all QA / developers /management to see.

tnx.